# Why would a full suite of Jasmine tests fail when running smaller suites individually works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jasmine, protractor

I have a protractor configuration file with the following suite glob patterns:

```js
  suites: {
    all: ['**/*.spec.js'],
    ui: ['ui/**/*.spec.js'],
    api: ['api/**/*.spec.js']
  },
```

If I, on a Mac, run `npm run protractor` (with the default suite of `all`), the tests run fine.
If another person on the team, on a Mac, runs `npm run protractor`, the tests run fine.
If the other person on the team, on a Ubuntu VM on a Windows host:

- runs `npm run protractor`, the tests die. Specifically, the first line of the `onPrepare` throws an error.
- runs `npm run protractor --suite=ui`, the tests run fine
- runs `npm run protractor --suite=api`, the tests run fine
- runs `npm run protractor --suite=ui,api`, the `onPrepare` errors again

At this point, I'm wondering if the issue is the VM's nodejs resources when Jasmine initially traverses the spec files. There are 15k+ `it`s in the full suite. The `onPrepare` working fine outside of suite all makes me think the actual thrown error was a red herring (it was a database call with the `mysql` package that threw a connection timeout).

Comment: What's the error? Running out of memory maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can make a guess this is related to how different OS read your `**` path. I'd recommend to use `path` library to solve this. Make sure you install it and then

```
let path = require('path');

let specs = path.resolve('**/*.spec.js'); // it should be /your/working/direction/**/*.spec.js
console.log(specs) // to confirm your assumption

exports.config = {
  suites: {
    all: [specs],
    ui: ['ui/**/*.spec.js'],
    api: ['api/**/*.spec.js']
  },
}
```

But there might be something else, that causes the problem